# Need new converter or special hose?

Tags: tools, powertools, compressor, hose

I would like to connect my bike nozzle to a new compressor I just bought. However the compressor have an odd (?) connector.

Can someone from the pictures below see if I need to buy a new converter for the compressor or a special hose is needed?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The first image looks like a Hansen style plug, while the second image looks like maybe a schrader coupling (hard to tell without seeing the end of the coupling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a quick connector at the compressor... it looks something like this:

[image: quick connector]

The things to get right are whether the threaded end is male or female, the size of the threads (1/4 NPT is common in the US, but YMMV), and the compatibility with the connector you already have (if you don't feel like changing it as well). I can't really tell, but it might be a type M connector. Just to make things more complicated, there are different sizes out there.

If it was me, I'd unscrew the connector from the compressor and bring everything to a store that stocks such things to put it all together. In the US, any big box Home Depot/Lowes/Menards would have that.

Comment: Be aware is a variety of such connectors, and most are incompatible with each other. You want to choose one standard and stick with it.   Don't just pick the one the local junque shop happens to stock.